# Getting the vertices content on a LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9

Tags: c++, directx

How to correctly get the vertices content on a LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9?
When I initiate it to be rendered later I know what vertices and the sizeof it that were used, but supposing I don't, is it **possible** to get them later into a pointer?

```
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 Stream_Data;
if(p1->GetStreamSource(0, &Stream_Data, &Offset, &XStride) == D3D_OK)
{
    void* pVoid;
    Stream_Data->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy( ??????, pVoid, sizeof( ?????? ) );
    Stream_Data->Unlock();

    Stream_Data->Release();
}
```

Comment: "What kind of evil or stupid programmer on surface of Earth uses a type name like this?" - I thought. Then I realized this is just a normal WinAPI typedef.

Comment: should I edit the title?

Comment: No, it's not your fault, Microsoft should get their stuff together ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex format is user-defined, although there are ways to retrieve it:

```
D3DVERTEXBUFFER_DESC desc;
Stream_Data->GetDesc(&desc);
```

Now, `desc.FVF` field will contain the flexible vertex format mask which tells you which fields are used in the vertex (as listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). An alternative way to describe the vertex format would be using vertex declarations, which are a little more descriptive, though [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes how to obtain them from FVF.

For example, you might get the following FVF: `D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE | D3DFVF_TEX1`. This would correspond to the following vertex structure:

```
struct Vertex
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 position;
    D3DXVECTOR3 normal;
    D3DCOLOR diffuse;
    float tu, tv;
};
```

Comment: Haha thanks for your answer, it is correct, I had something on that (updated question) but my problem is that I was doing it on DIP, on which i read on msdn that `DrawPrimitive calls will not succeed with any outstanding lock count on any currently set vertex buffer.` =(